# Network share accessible on one PC, but not a different PC with same user credentials

Tags: active-directory, network-share

I have a very odd issue. I'm trying to access a network share on my organization. Like in the title, it works on one PC, but not another, with the same credentials. The effective access shows me having access, and I'm in the allowed AD groups with the correct domains.

Is there anything I can check between these PC's for any more information? Group policies perhaps?

Thanks!

Edit: Both these PC's are Windows 10 Enterprise Edition, Version 1709.
Not sure what happened, but now after 6 months of the issue, it has magically been solved. I assume corporate IT had found and resolved the issue. I will update the question as I receive a response for what had been fixed.

Edit 2: Still awaiting response

Comment: Check the Date/Time.

Comment: You need to provide the Windows version of each system.

Comment: `it works on one PC, but not another` - What happens exactly? Do you get any messages, error or otherwise?

Comment: @GregAskew Thanks for reminding me, I updated the question.

Comment: @joeqwerty This has been resolved now as per my edit, but it was giving me the typical error: "Windows cannot access <fileshare> You do not have permission to access <fileshare>. Contact your network administrator to request access."